# Explanations over parallel code execution and further performance gain in a simple example

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, concurrency

playing around with multithreaded programming with `c++11` threads, I wanted to make sure that diving the algorithm into data independent parts and processing them in parallel should decrease the overall runtime.

Lets say the task is to find a maximum in an array of integers for which the parallelization is pretty simple - each thread finds a local maximum on particular chunk of data, then at the end when all of local maximums are found, we should find the final maximum from local maximums - so the runtime should decrease up to 3-4 times with 4 hardware threads (on my pc it is 4)

the code

```
void max_el(
    std::vector<int>& v,
    std::vector<int>::value_type& max, 
    const int& n_threads=1,
    const unsigned int& tid = 0)
{
    max = v[tid];
    for (size_t i = tid, end = v.size(); i < end; i += n_threads)
    {
        if (v[i] > max)
        {
            max = v[i];
        }
    }
}

void max_el_concurrent(std::vector<int>& v)
{
    int n_threads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
    std::cout << n_threads << " threads" << std::endl;
    std::vector<std::thread> workers(n_threads);
    std::vector<int> res(n_threads);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n_threads; ++i)
    {
        workers[i] = std::thread(max_el, std::ref(v), std::ref(res[i]), n_threads, i);
    }

    for (auto& worker: workers)
    {
        worker.join();
    }


    std::vector<int>::value_type final_max;
    max_el(std::ref(res), std::ref(final_max));
    std::cout << final_max << std::endl;
}


void max_el_sequential(std::vector<int>& v)
{
    std::vector<int>::value_type max;
    std::cout << "sequential" << std::endl;
    max_el(v, max);
    std::cout << max << std::endl;
}


template< class Func, class Container >
void profile(Func func, Container cont)
{
    high_resolution_clock::time_point start, now;
    double runtime = 0.0f;

    start = high_resolution_clock::now();
    func(cont);
    now = high_resolution_clock::now();
    runtime = duration<double>(now - start).count();
    std::cout << "runing time = " << runtime << " sec" << std::endl;
}


#define NUM_ELEMENTS 100000000

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.reserve(NUM_ELEMENTS + 100);
    //  filling
    std::cout << "data is ready, running ... " << std::endl;
    profile(max_el_sequential, v);  // 0.506731 sec

    profile(max_el_concurrent, v);  // 0.26108 sec why only ~2 times faster !?

    return 0;
}
```

Despite that `std::thread::hardware_concurrency` returns `4` execution of this code shows onlyy 2 times performance gain compared to sequential algorithm.

Taking into account that `/proc/cpu/info` shows `2 cpus` with `2 cores` for each and the fact that there's no any lock/unlock, I/O or threads communications overhead in the code, I expect the theory working just fine and at least `x3`, `x4` times runtime decrease, however this is not happening in practice...

So why there's such a behavour ?

What's exactly going on there ?

Comment: How many physical cores is that, only 2 right?

Comment: @harold this is what I can not answer I think, however `cat /proc/cpuinfo` shows 2 cores for each processor (2) ... which is core I5 5200

Comment: If the array is large enough (well beyond cache size), a simple search for maximum value may be fast enough to be ram bandwidth bound and virtually no gain. On the other hand, I found that a relatively small loop used for merge wasn't memory bound, in which case using 4 cores was about 3 times as fast in a merge sort for a large array.

Comment: Ok i5-5200U is definitely a dual core processor. With hyperthreading, however, so it will show as 4. Hyperthreads increase performance sometimes, not always, you could compare with 2 threads and see how it goes.

Comment: @harold If it dual-core processor why then hardware concurrency returns 4 ?? , and ... I just ran with 2 threads and it gave 0.2778 sec - not so slow

Comment: Because the processor looks and (semantically) acts like a 4-core processor (and mostly it somewhat better to treat it that way, but there are caveats..), it just doesn't have the performance of one because it actually runs two hardware threads per core.

Comment: @RustyX sorry what do you mean false sharing ?

Comment: Just FYI: Intel Core i7-6700K@4.00GHz. 4 Threads: seq. 0.053 s, par. 0.024 s. With your default, 8 Threads, sequential is faster than threaded.  CLang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my system (Core i7-5820k), your application seems to be ***memory-bound***.

The speedup I got was 2.9 (with 12 threads).

On my system, max DRAM bandwidth is 45GB/s:

[image: vtune system bandwidth DRAM]

Single-threaded run of your application used around 16GB/s:

[image]

And with 12 threads: 45GB/s:

[image]

(had same results and overall execution time with 3..11 threads)

The way you're striding over contiguous memory in this loop isn't too efficient:

```
    for (size_t i = tid, end = v.size(); i < end; i += n_threads)
```

Memory is read into the L2 cache in contiguous blocks, so doing this in parallel is going to be wasteful; with a 64 byte cache line and a 4-byte `int` this is going to load the *whole array* in every thread, up to 16 threads. It is also very wasteful for the L2 cache, as only a small part of each cache line is actually used (we assume the threads aren't perfectly in sync and the distance between the active regions quickly exceeds the L2 size).

---

Additional remarks:

- Do not time I/O (that includes `std::cout`), this will skew the results.
- Try not to write to adjacent memory from different threads (like you do with the `res` vector), or your application will suffer from [false sharing](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/avoiding-and-identifying-false-sharing-among-threads). You want to keep a distance of at least 64 bytes between memory written by different threads. As a quick fix, collect the local maximum into a *local variable* and write `max` only once at the end.

Fixing both of these had no significant effect on overall performance in this particular case, however.

Finally, your CPU (Core i5-5200) is a 2-core, hyper-threaded processor. According to Intel, the speedup of hyper-threading is [on average 30%](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/how-to-determine-the-effectiveness-of-hyper-threading-technology-with-an-application). That means that you should expect a max speedup of 2.6 (2 + 2*0.3) and not 4.0.

Comment: yeah these notes are interesting, but I knew that any optimization regarding efficient memory usage shouldn't make big difference, just because the additional overhead is very small ... thanks for links